# Getting data from Stdout in real time in Golang

Tags: go

In my program, I would like to be able to monitor the execution of some console commands in real time.

Here are two examples of code that displays data in real time in the console, but on the web page the data is not displayed in real time, but only after the completion of the command.

Please advise how can I get real time data in a web page?

*In both examples: The console displays data in real time. On the web page, the data is not displayed in real time, but only after the command is completed. I need to display data in real time on a web page.*

Example 1

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainLogic)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func mainLogic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "8.8.8.8", "-c5")
    var stdBuffer bytes.Buffer
    mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &stdBuffer)
    cmd.Stdout = mw
    cmd.Stderr = mw
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, stdBuffer.String())
}
```

Example 2

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "io"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainLogic)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func mainLogic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "8.8.8.8", "-c5")
    var stdout []byte
    var errStdout, errStderr error
    stdoutIn, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderrIn, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Start() failed with '%s'\n", err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        stdout, errStdout = copyAndCapture(os.Stdout, stdoutIn)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    _, errStderr = copyAndCapture(os.Stderr, stderrIn)
    wg.Wait()
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    if errStdout != nil || errStderr != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to capture stdout or stderr\n")
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(stdout))
}

func copyAndCapture(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    var out []byte
    buf := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
        if n > 0 {
            d := buf[:n]
            out = append(out, d...)
            _, err := w.Write(d)
            if err != nil {
                return out, err
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil
            }
            return out, err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your first implementation works, why is the second completely different? Why not use the same approach?

Comment: Perhaps you misread my problem. Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. Both versions of the code work the same way. The console displays data in real time. On the web page, the data is not displayed in real time, but only after the command is completed. I need to display data in real time on a web page.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem, but they don't work the same way at all. The first one, that behaves as desired, is simple: set up command, set its stdout, run it. The second, which doesn't work as desired, is completely different, and uses pipes, and goroutines, and waitgroups, and async command execution. Why?

Comment: Because I am open to any solution to my problem. Because I show that I tried different options, and do not require me to write the entire code for me from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP responses are buffered by default for performance reasons, so you need to explicitly call [`Flush`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Flusher) in order to send data immediately.

If you want to do this from a writer assigned to the outputs of `exec.Cmd`, you can wrap the `http.ResponseWriter` in a type which will call `Flush` for you on every `Write`.

```
type flushWriter interface {
    io.Writer
    http.Flusher
}

type flusher struct {
    w flushWriter
}

func (f *flusher) Write(d []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := f.w.Write(d)
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }
    f.w.Flush()
    return n, nil
}

...

if w, ok := w.(flushWriter); ok {
    cmd.Stdout = &flusher{w}
    cmd.Stderr = &flusher{w}
}
```

If you want a copy of the data, you could the use the `io.MultiWriter` to capture the output while it's being written. Here we also cover the case where the `http.ResponseWriter` is not an `http.Flusher`, but that is only likely to happen if you already wrapped in via some other middleware.

```
var mw io.Writer
var buff bytes.Buffer
if w, ok := w.(flushWriter); ok {
    mw = io.MultiWriter(&buff, &flusher{w})
} else {
    mw = io.MultiWriter(&buff, w)
}
cmd.Stdout = mw
cmd.Stderr = mw
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like magic to me, but it works.

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask one more question? Is it possible in Go to subscribe to the newdata receive event in cmd.Stdout? I would like to analyze the data received from cmd.Stdout and perform various actions based on the analysis.

Comment: @WayMax, there's no "subscription", the command calls `Write` on whatever is assigned to `Stdout`. If you want to copy the data, you can just use an `io.MultiWriter` like you did originally.